# problema al actualizar BD MySQL con ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo un problema al actualizar mi BD de MySQL con un ResultSet. Adjunto fuente actual.

```
public void insertaTabla(Object[] empleados) throws SQLException{

    modelo.insertRow(modelo.getRowCount(), empleados);

    int ultimaFila = modelo.getRowCount() - 1;

    Object idEmp = modelo.getValueAt(ultimaFila, 0);
    Object nombre = modelo.getValueAt(ultimaFila, 1);
    Object apellido = modelo.getValueAt(ultimaFila, 2);
    Object feAlta = modelo.getValueAt(ultimaFila, 3);
    Object sueldo = modelo.getValueAt(ultimaFila, 4);
    Object totalVentas = modelo.getValueAt(ultimaFila, 5);
    Object idDep = modelo.getValueAt(ultimaFila, 6);

    rs.updateObject("idEmp", idEmp);
    rs.updateObject("nombre", nombre);
    rs.updateObject("apellido", apellido);
    rs.updateObject("feAlta", feAlta);
    rs.updateObject("sueldo", sueldo);
    rs.updateObject("totalVentas", totalVentas);
    rs.updateObject("idDep", idDep);

    rs.insertRow();

    validate();
    repaint();
}
```

este es el código que inserta en el JTable, y desde este tengo que actualizar mi base de datos, pero me devuelve un puntero nulo en esta línea *rs.updateObject("idEmp", idEmp);*

el ResultSet lo tengo definido como atributo de clase y luego lo uso para llenar el JTable. Los valores son recibidos del array de Object que se le pasa por parámetro al método empleados y no le llega vacío ya lo he comprobado. Tengo que aclarar, que no estoy muy seguro de hacer esto con ResultSet (no tengo mucha experiencia con esto) pero tengo que hacerlo así.

un saludo y gracias de antemano

Comment: [Según la documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#updateObject(int,%20java.lang.Object)) `updateObject` **no actualiza los valores en la base de datos**. Tampoco entiendo por qué tu método se llama `insertaTabla` y tú hablas de *actualizar*  (¿actualizar o insertar?). Generalmente, para cualquiera de los dos casos, lo que se suele usar es un `PreparedStatement`, cuando lo que se quiere es insertar o actualizar datos en la tabla. [Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/112912/29967) (en el apartado `II`).

Comment: @A.Cedano agradezco tu comentario, pero me exigen que sea tocando directamente el resultSet. Se que se debe hacer con Prepared, pero como digo, me exigen que sea directamente con el ResultSet. Me gustaría saber como capturar la última fila del JTable y sus datos, una vez capturados ya si puedo hacer la actualización como me piden, ya que en un JDialog introduzco los datos y estos son introducidos en un array de Object y este array es introducido en el JTable, si capturo la ultima fila, podré hacer las operaciones con el ResultSet. De nuevo gracias por tu comentario

Comment: David, como muestra el enlace de más arriba, `updatObject` debe recibir dos parámetros: `int columnIndex, Object x`, en cambio, **tú estás pasando una cadena como 1er parámetro cuando ahí debe ir el número de la columna, empezando por `1`** y en el segundo parámetro el nuevo valor. En cuanto a obtener los valores de la última file, ¿no los obtienes con tu código? ¿Has depurado las variables que recuperas, imprimiéndolas o algo así?